# How to stop the first character in a text box from being space?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox and want user can not enter space in first textbox.the user can enter space in any where textbox apart of Beginning textbox.my computer = allow my computer = not allow (space in begining) , space maybe one or two or more.

Comment: Why don't you validate the input when the user has finished typing? You could for example check if `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text)`.

Comment: Rather than disallowing space , why dont you remove space if any.

Comment: you can do this by checking the `Substring` of the first character that's one way.. to follow up on `AshReva` comment just to a `.Trim()` on the Text that's entered

Comment: `TrimStart()` is your friend

Comment: It would really help if you told us **why** you want to "stop the first character in a text box from being space". What problem does that solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really insist on doing this using one of the Events I would suggest you do it in the `Text_Changed` Event I have set you a simple way to do it..

```
private void txtaddgroup_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (textBox.Text.StartsWith(" "))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Can not have spaces in the First Position");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean will not work..it works perfectly fine you need to explain what type of Application you are doing this in.. `WinForms or Web Application` and I tested this it works perfect when you are typing realtime hit the space bar and you will see.. look at what event I am doing it in vs what event you are doing it it..mine checks at the time do not use the KeyPressEvent

Comment: when i trying type space program message but space do not clear and textbox have space !

Comment: then just add `textBox.Text = textBox.Text.TrimStart(' ');` before the MessageBox

Comment: not a problem I would suggest in your spare time to just practice coding and learn about all the basic methods that go along with some of the .Net controls. good luck and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Implement a keypress event where you get rid of any spaces, read more [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/b38b9d6a-2a49-45ae-aa7f-65ae1a18e598/).

Answer (score 0):

Add this bit of code to your KeyDown event handler to stop the space key ever being registered:

```
//Check to see if the first character is a space
        if (UsernameTextBox.SelectionStart == 0) //This is the first character
        {
            //Now check to see if the key pressed is a space
            if (e.KeyValue == 32)
            {
                //Stop the key registering
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
```

32 if the Key Code for the space character.

Answer (score 0):

You should call this function with parameter as 'e' on `KeyPress` event:

Here 32 is the ASCII value of space

```cs
void SpaceValidation(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 32 && ActiveControl.Text.Length == 0)
        e.Handled = true;       
}

private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    SpaceValidation(e);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please fix your sample code to include the `sender`  input parameter as well.